# How to store username after logout and show it in TextInput on next login?

Tags: react-native

I have a login screen where I will enter a username and then after login I will go to home screen.

Now what I want is once the user comes out of the app and then open it again then it has to show the the username that has entered before.

How can I do this? I am using react-native-router-flux for navigation.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  View,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class AsyncStorageExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        myKey: null
    };
  }


  async getKey() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key')
      if (this.state.myKey === value) {
        Actions.dashboard();
        }
      this.setState({ myKey: value });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error retrieving data' + error);
    }
  }

  async saveKey(value) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error saving data' + error);
    }
  }

  async resetKey() {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('@MySuperStore:key');
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
      this.setState({ myKey: value });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error resetting data' + error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to Demo AsyncStorage!
        </Text>

        <TextInput
          style={styles.formInput}
          placeholder="Enter key you want to save!"
          value={this.state.myKey}
          onChangeText={(value) => this.saveKey(value)}
          />

        <Button
          style={styles.formButton}
          onPress={this.getKey.bind(this)}
          title="Get Key"
          color="#2196f3"
          accessibilityLabel="Get Key"
        />

        <Button
          style={styles.formButton}
          onPress={this.resetKey.bind(this)}
          title="Reset"
          color="#f44336"
          accessibilityLabel="Reset"
        />

        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Stored key is = {this.state.myKey}
        </Text>


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 30,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  formInput: {
    paddingLeft: 5,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#555555",
  },
  formButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#555555",
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});
```

Using this I can get like this

[image]

When I enter some text then I will navigate to next screen; after that, if I come out of my app and open it again, then the previous value is not showing up in TextInput.

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: save username into `asyncstorage` or `database`, then after logout get the same if exist and show onto textinput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **AsyncStorage** component of React Native. For more info [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

You can set a value of user on logout.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('UseName', 'name of user');
```

On login form get value from AsyncStorage in **componentWillMount()** method.

```
 AsyncStorage.getItem('UserName')
      .then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                this.setState({UserName:data}) //store data in state
                                }
       }).done();
```

Comment: @Dhara , I have updated my question plz tell me what is wrong with my code

Comment: There is no error but once i come out of the app and then open it agian butstill the previusly entered uesrname is not showing up in TextInput

Comment: @Rama you are calling a getKey method to get the value of Username right? and this method is calling on click of getKey button. so, try to print console in getKey method and show what is the value are you getting

Comment: @Rama I run your code and it's working fine for me.

Comment: what exactly i want is once if I enter some value in Text Input and click the button it will go to next screen then i will exit from the app and after some time when i will open the app then I want Text Input to show the previous entered value in Placeholder .

Comment: For that, you have to get value from AsyncStorage in componenwillmount() method and set this value in the state (myKey).